# adding two numbers in android

Tags: android

I tried to create a calculator type of addition in android. For that purpose I used the following code.

But the ans is always a 0..

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    EditText num1,num2;
    TextView resu;
    int res;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        num1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etnum1);
        num2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etnum2);
        resu=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        String mynum1=num1.getText().toString();
        final int mnum1=Integer.parseInt(mynum1);

        String mynum2=num2.getText().toString();
        final int mnum2=Integer.parseInt(mynum2);

        add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                res=mnum1+mnum2;
                resu.setText(Integer.toString(res));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have also tried

```
resu.setText(String.valueOf(res));
```

But the answer is always zero !

What have I done wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

Include the statements for getting the numbers inside on click listener
it is shown below:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

EditText num1,num2;
TextView resu;
int res;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    num1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etnum1);
    num2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etnum2);
    resu=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);






    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String mynum1=num1.getText().toString();
            String mynum2=num2.getText().toString();

            res=Integer.parseInt(mynum1)+Integer.parseInt(mynum2);
            resu.setText(Integer.toString(res));
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Chnage your button setOnClickListener code and also check edittext values for NULL or empty before parsing to Integer as: :

```
 add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           int mnum1,mnum2;
         if(isNotNullNotEmptyNotWhiteSpaceOnlyByJava(num1.getText().toString())){

              mnum1=Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString());
         } 
         else{
                  mnum1=0;
          }  
         if(isNotNullNotEmptyNotWhiteSpaceOnlyByJava(num2.getText().toString())){

          mnum2=Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString());
         } 
         else{
               mnum2=0;
          }  

            res=mnum1+mnum2;
            resu.setText(Integer.toString(res));
        }
public  boolean isNotNullNotEmptyNotWhiteSpaceOnlyByJava(  
    String string)  
{  
   return string != null && !string.isEmpty() && !string.trim().isEmpty();  
}
```

currently you are not getting latest value entered by user on button click from EditText's

Comment: @user1897165 : see my answer to avoid other error's you must check EditText's value's for Null or empty before parsing it to Integer

Comment: well well well...m not dat good at java or android....but a basic app developer wid a little knowledge of both d worlds...
thnks again !!

Answer (score 0):

You got the user input when the activity was *created* (in `onCreate`).

You need to take in the user input when the button has been clicked, not just add it when it's clicked. Change your code to this:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    EditText num1,num2;
    TextView resu;
    int res;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        num1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etnum1);
        num2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etnum2);
        resu=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4); 

        add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String mynum1=num1.getText().toString();
                int mnum1=Integer.parseInt(mynum1);

                String mynum2=num2.getText().toString();
                int mnum2=Integer.parseInt(mynum2);

                res=mnum1+mnum2;
                resu.setText(Integer.toString(res));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You should use a [try](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html)-[catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) though because this app will crash if the user presses the button with blank text.

Answer (score 0):

for adding you can use:

```
     flot a=(flot)(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1)).getText().toString());
     flot b=(flot)(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2)).getText().toString());
     flot out=a+b
```

Comment: Please add a description of how this solves the users question. Also, please read [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {

    EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    double num1=Double.parseDouble(e1.getText().toString());
    double num2=Double.parseDouble(e2.getText().toString());
    double sum= num1 + num2;
    t1.setText(Double.toString(sum));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add.setOnClickListener(v -> 
{
    int mynum1 = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString());

    int mynum2 = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString());

    res = mynum1 + mynum2;
    resu.setText(String.toInteger(res));
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Full disclosure: From my personal blog

[Addition program in android](http://stackentry.blogspot.in/2016/01/addition-of-two-numbers-in-android.html)

XML and Java code for addition of two numbers in android

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
private EditText editText,editText2,editText4;
    int v1,v2,v3;
    String s="ans";
private Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        editText4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
         v1=Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
         v2=Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
         v3=v1+v2;

         s=String.valueOf(v3);
        editText4.setText(s);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

activitymain.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="800dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you answering a post that is 3 years old with just a link?

Comment: Let me try to salvage this.

Comment: Mohan, please read  [Your answer is in another castle: When is an answer not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370)  that may explain why your posts can easily be deleted with what you did.

Comment: As for your other post, you are off to a good start getting Answer-banned with spam.

Comment: A beginner knowledge is education, My answer is only for Beginner not for Damn good android expert